# When exactly are we looking back at the past from future. Is it at the start of the due time or at the end of the due time?

Tags: future, future-perfect, prepositions

My question is simple and specific. Please look at the following

What is the difference between

> 1. I will submit the report by 5 pm tomorrow.
> 2. I will have submitted the report by 5 pm tomorrow.

If they are not the same, then please tell me what the difference is between them.

If they both are one and the same and the difference is one of POV, then please look at following.

When I say, *I will have submitted the report by 5 pm tomorrow*. My question is what time am I referring to? Is it at 5 pm tomorrow or starting from 5:01 pm and not before. I mean this also includes the possibility of me submitting the report at 5 pm also? Am I right?

And also, when I say

1. I will submit the report by 5 pm tomorrow.
   (Looking from now)
2. I will have submitted the report by 5 pm.
   (Looking from 5:00 pm or 5:01 pm? I think after 5:00 pm because according to you ***by 5 pm*** includes either 'before' or 'at')

Do the two sentences have the same meaning? Is the difference based on POV? If not, then please tell me what the difference is between them.

This has been confusing me for almost two days now. I have spent almost two days on this and still I am clueless about this.

Thank you so so much.

Comment: If you're referring to Colin Fine's answer in Rob_Ster's link, there are two time points: one when the sentence is created (call this T), and a second related to the sense of *will* vs *will have* (call these U and V). 'T' is presumably 'now', before the deadline. 'U' is a commitment or claim, so it is also 'now'. The perfect tense associated with 'V' gives it a sense of completion. That completion (and hence 'V') is claimed to happen *at or before* the deadline. Your '1' is a commitment; '2' is a claim about the future. Otherwise, both have the same intent.

Comment: Regrading the specific meaning of "by 5.pm" this refers to any time from the time of speaking (now) until 5 pm itself. But NOT 5.01 pm. If you promise the report by 5 pm (17.00) tomorrow but you deliver it one minute later, you have broken your promise, although a single minute is hardly going to make any significant difference.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the OP was confused by Colin Fine's use of the term [viewpoint](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118234/142322), specifically that form 2 is *looking into the past ... from a point in the future". Nice edit, by the way.

Comment: @Lawrence could well be, but unless the OP returns and clarifies, we'll never know for sure. For someone who's been battling with a language problem for over two days, you'd think he would have commented by now.... Maybe your explanation was enough to clear up his confusion.

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. My apologies for not being able to answer you earlier as I was at my work and you know policing is tough in a country like India. I am truly sorry.

I know that they both basically mean the same and are different ways of looking at the same thing.

I want to know what is the 'point in future' that we are looking from into the past? This is my question. Because we speak after the event has completed. I want to know when exactly is that point. Is it at 5:00 pm or 5:00:01 pm or at 5:01 pm. This is bothering me. 

Please help me.

Thank you and sorry

Comment: @policewala The 'sense of completion' view has the 'looking back' time at the time of submission - that is, 5pm or whatever earlier time (e.g. 4pm) the report was submitted.

Comment: But Lawrence sir, one can submit at 5 pm also, so how can I look back from 5 pm? Because for me to look back from 5 pm means the work should have completed before 5 pm and not at 5 pm. How can submitting at 5 pm and also the event having got completed by 5 pm reconcile? To me they seem contradictory. This is immensely confusing to me. Please help me.